# Как сделать 2 колонки на Flexbox

Tags: css, css3, html5, frontend, flexbox

Как при помощи флекс-технологии построить 2 колонки одинаковой ширины? При этом элементы внутри колонок не должны переносится на следующую строку.

```css
.block__section {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.block_text__span {
 background: #29c5e5;
 color: #29c5e5;
 padding: 0 8px;
 margin-right: 6px;
 height: 10px;
}

.title_pattern {
 height: 14px;
 margin-top: 29px;
}

.block {
 flex: 1 0;
 width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block__section">
   <div class="block">
      <div class="block_text">
         <ul class="block_text__ul">
            <li class="block_text__li"><span class="block_text__span">. 
               </span> About WhiteSquare
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="img/Title pattern.png" class="title_pattern" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="block">
      <div class="block_text">
         <ul class="block_text__ul">
            <li class="block_text__li"><span class="block_text__span">. 
               </span> a word from OUR ceo
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="img/Title pattern.png" class="title_pattern" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что сделано и что не получается?
Рекомендую для начала почитать https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 3):

Пример

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;  
}
.flex-child {  
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;   
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.flex-child:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div class="elem">elem</div>
    <div class="elem">elem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div class="elem">elem 2</div>
    <div class="elem">elem 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
}

.item:nth-of-type(1) {}

.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    первая колонка
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    вторая колонка
  </div>
</div>
```